# How to process information in data classes received from an API

Tags: json, kotlin, data-class

I’m new to Kotlin, and have found the awesome Data Class!

So, I’m using Data Classes to get some information from a JSON API, but I’d like to process the data before using it to save some time/processing power.

To make things easier, I’ll illustrate an easy example:

```
data class UserApi(val name: String, val born: Int)
```

As I said, I'm receiving the data from a JSON API, but creating a User programmatically would look like this:

```
val userApi: UserApi = UserApi("Catelyn", 1990)
```

Now, instead of calculating how old the User is every time by:

```
"currentYear - userApi.born" // Calculating an approximate age
```

Ofc without changing the API, I’d just like to get an immutable val like this:

```
userApi.age
```

Is this possible?
I’m thinking something like:

```
interface UserApi {
    val name: String
    val born: Int
}

data class User(override val name: String, override val born: Int) : UserApi {
    // Calculating an approximate age
    val age: Int = "currentYear - userApi.born"
}

val user: User = User("Catelyn", 1990) // Or get the data from an API.

// Getting the age of the User like this:
user.age // Same as "currentYear - userApi.born".
```

Is something like this the way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mix in additional property into your data class:

```
data class UserApi(val name: String, val born: Int) {
  val age get() = LocalDate.now().year - born
}

val mikesAge = UserApi("Mike", 1990).age
```

This property will be automatically calculated every time it's accessed.
See the "custom getter" example [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters).

Or you can just define the new property. This property will be calculated only once:

```
data class UserApi(val name: String, val born: Int) {
  val age = LocalDate.now().year - born
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you for your input. I wonder if the age property is calculated once (in the constructor) and saved as an Int or if it's calculated each time the getter is called. 
Let's say that the `LocalDate.now().year - born` is a **very** time consuming calculation, is it calculated each time i call `UserApi("Mike", 1990).age` or does the call only return an already saved Int?

Comment: Yes, you can just define new property. Please see updated answer.